# Boot manager missing error in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I have a Sony Vaio sve14118fxw laptop. Every time I start the laptop first the Sony Vaio logo appears and then the screen goes black and an error message appears after that saying "BOOTMGR missing".

Answer (score 2):

You should have received a Windows 7 installation CD with the Laptop.

**Problem:**

BOOTMGR missing. The Windows 7 boot manager has been corrupted and/or deleted

## **Solution:**

**With CD:**

1. Put the CD in the DVD tray, close the DVD tray
2. When the Sony Logo appears, press the required keys to enter the boot selector. It maybe written on the screen labeled as "Boot Selection", it is typically one of these keys: F2, F8, or F12
3. Once the boot selection screen opens, select the Windows 7 CD you entered in, it should be labeled as some cryptic string of numbers/letters.
4. You'll boot up the CD, select your language and Keyboard options, click next.
5. Now, in the lower left hand corner of the window, there should be something called *Repair my computer* or something similar. Click that.
6. Enter all necessary login details, if any. Then select *Automatic Startup Repair* or "Startup Repair"
7. It should fix the problem automatically, It'll restart the computer itself.

**Without CD:**

8. You'll have to find yourself an copy of Windows 7 in an *.iso* format.
9. Burn it to a USB using Microsoft provided tools
10. Boot up using the USB as the primary boot device
11. Follow the steps in **With CD* from Step 4 and onwards

Comment: What a clear, well written answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an installation disc for Windows 7 (on a DVD or a bootable USB)?

If yes, then just pop that in your optical drive/USB -> Restart your machine and boot from installation disc/USB and chose the Auto Recovery option.

That will solve the BOOTMGR issue.